# Offset data down a cell if cell contains data

Tags: excel, vba, indexing, match, offset

I need to modify the below code to offset dynamically depending on if the cell contains data to a maximum of 5.

Then if past 5, I want it to display a msg box to display a error.

I have this working VB code:

```
Evaluate("OFFSET(INDEX(B$6:B$72,MATCH(""" & Me.Pool_Numbers.Value & """,A$6:A$72,0)),1,0)") = Change_Pool.Value
```

I want it to look something like this, but I don't know how to implement it.

```
for every cell that contains data, 
set offset value +1 

Evaluate("OFFSET(INDEX(B$6:B$72,MATCH(""" & Me.Pool_Numbers.Value & """,A$6:A$72,0)), * OFFSET AMOUNT * ,0)") = Change_Pool.Value

If offset > 5
msgbox "You cannot do this blablabla"
```

Comment: It might be helpful if you [efit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57589174/edit) to provide sample data and expected result. You can upload screencaps to http://imgur.com and link to them here

Comment: You mean that, given a cell in a row, you want to check if the next 5 rows got data or not? And if rows containing data are more than 5, then return *you cannot do this bla bla bla*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Evaluate method in this context returns a Range object.  So, we can assign the resulting range to an object variable, and then we can set up a For/Next loop to check the first five cells for an empty cell in which to enter the desired value.

```
Dim targetCell As Range
Set targetCell = Evaluate("OFFSET(INDEX(A$6:A$72,MATCH(""" & Me.ComboBox1.Value & """,B$6:B$72,0)),1,0)")

Dim emptyCellFound As Boolean
emptyCellFound = False

Dim i As Long
For i = 0 To 4
    If Len(targetCell.Offset(i, 0).Value) = 0 Then
        targetCell.Offset(i, 0).Value = Change_Pool.Value
        emptyCellFound = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next i

If Not emptyCellFound Then
    MsgBox "No empty cell found!", vbExclamation
End If
```

Comment: You've nailed it, home my explanation was not too complicated, Thank you so much!

Comment: That's great, glad I could help.  Cheers!